# CSS only works internal in Safari?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to use this map marker: [Codepen Map marker CSS only](http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/ClguF).
But when I try to define the style in a external stylesheet it doesn't work in Safari.

Here's the CSS [Codepen CSS-Stylesheet](http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/ClguF.css):

```
.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #89849b;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin:after {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.pulse {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
  transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #89849b;
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}

@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

What's wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may need to prefix some of those properties for Safari as Codepen is adding those automatically.

Comment: Might have something to do with the SASS not being converted with the stylesheet that's external.

Comment: I've downloaded the zip-file and used CSS, but still doesn't work ...

Comment: Yeah, but your sass isn't being processed as css. It's working, but it still needs to be converted before you can load it as an external stylesheet. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/Mz7P9/

Comment: In this Codepen, see CSS options: it isn't CSS but Sass, a CSS preprocessor, with another CSS file called a Reset CSS (probably the one from teh mighty Eric Meyer here) **AND** -prefix-free live JS management of vendor prefixes (`-webkit`, `-moz-`, `-ms-` and alike). Don't use the latter in production, use a Sass compiler with Autoprefixr option or task or … If you'd want to know how to add these vendor prefixes manually, where would you find the info? On MDN ([MDN transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility)) and [caniuse](http://caniuse.com)